# support all browsers with browserlist and autoprefixer

Tags: css, browser, autoprefixer

I am using an autoprefixer that utilizes browserlist.

https://github.com/ai/browserslist

I was thinking about supporting every version of every browser by doing this. 
This means support all versions greater than 0. Which is every version.

Firefox > 0

Chrome > 0

Explorer >0

...Continue for every browser, but it says this in the browserlist github readme.

"Browserslist works with separated versions of browsers. You should avoid queries like Firefox > 0."

I do not understand what this is saying

Comment: They say _don't use Firefox > 0_ which simply means _all versions_, and they say that because there is no point doing that since nobody is using Firefox 1.0 any more. Target the realistic amount of browsers

Comment: And it also means _you will only target Firefox_ with that query

Comment: Oh I understand now. So what I am using is Firefox > 20, Chrome > 20 , Explorer > 5 . Does that sound good?

Comment: Can't say as I don't use any of it ... and how I target browsers is based on my customers, not what sounds good ... use their online demo to see what your query will generate prefix for: [**Firefox > 20, Chrome > 20, Explorer > 5**](http://browserl.ist/?q=Firefox+%3E+20%2C+Chrome+%3E+20%2C+Explorer+%3E+5)